# debugging sockets and DLL's

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, sockets, dll

First question now answered if you want to skip to the bottom..

I'm developing comms between PDA's on .net 2.0 and our servers. Can't use WCF or I would have.

The comms model is like this:

[image: Comms Model]
And fortunately i've found working code form http://aviadezra.blogspot.com/2008/07/code-sample-net-sockets-multiple.html - that's where the image above comes from too.

The example app has messages from each client being broadcast to all other clients. I would like to be able to send a message from one client to another specific client. To do this i've modified the client app to have a from-ID and To-ID which is sent as part of the message.

Note: At this stage i'm doing proof of concept - i'll work on things like message headers (lengths, versions etc later).

From the project each client connection is handled by:

```
private void OnClientConnection(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        if (m_Closed)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            Socket clientSocket = m_socket.EndAccept(asyn);

            RaiseClientConnected(clientSocket);

            ConnectedClient connectedClient = new ConnectedClient(clientSocket);

            connectedClient.MessageRecived += OnMessageRecived;
            connectedClient.Disconnected += OnClientDisconnection;

            connectedClient.StartListen();

            long key = clientSocket.Handle.ToInt64();
            if (m_clients.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                Debug.Fail(string.Format(
                    "Client with handle key '{0}' already exist!", key));
            }

            m_clients[key] = connectedClient;

            // create the call back for any client connections...
            m_socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnection), null);

        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException odex)
        {
            Debug.Fail(odex.ToString(),
                "OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed");
        }
        catch (Exception sex)
        {
            Debug.Fail(sex.ToString(), 
                "OnClientConnection: Socket failed");
        }

    }
```

Class connectedClient holds the socket for that client.

When I send a message from client I do a lookup to see if that's in my list of sockets:

```
if (ListIDSocket.ContainsKey(ToID))
{
    PublishMessage(listLog, "ToID Found");
    SendAll = false;
}
```

ListIDSocket is:

```
private Dictionary<string, Socket> ListIDSocket = new Dictionary<string, Socket>();
```

Then..

```
if (SendAll)
   m_ServerTerminal.DistributeMessage(buffer);
else
  m_ServerTerminal.SendToSocket(ToID, socket, buffer);
```

So if message is to anyone, call DistributeMessage; if to single user, call SendToSocket.

The code in m_ServerTerminal is:

```
public void DistributeMessage(byte[] buffer)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (ConnectedClient connectedClient in m_clients.Values)
        {
            connectedClient.Send(buffer);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        Debug.Fail(se.ToString(), string.Format(
            "Buffer could not be sent"));
    }
}

public void SendToSocket(string ToID, Socket DestSocket, byte[] buffer)
{
    DistributeMessage(buffer);   // This line works
    ConnectedClient ToClient;
    long keyval = DestSocket.Handle.ToInt64();

    if (m_clients.ContainsKey(keyval))
    {
        ToClient = (ConnectedClient)m_clients[keyval];
        try
        {
            ToClient.Send(buffer);      // Nothing is received
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            Debug.Fail(se.ToString(), se.Message);
        }

        // DistributeMessage(buffer);    // This code here doesn't work
    }
}
```

DistributeMessage works fine. For debugging purposes i've included a call to DistributeMessage in my SendToSocket and this works if it's at the top.

If I move it down after I try writing to to the socket, it doesn't.

I don't get an exception on either way.

As it stands now, client gets one message when it should get two - one from DistributeMessage and one from SendToSocket.

The code for connectedclient.Send is:

```
public void Send(byte[] buffer)
{
   if (m_clientSocket == null)
   {
       throw new Exception("Can't send data. ConnectedClient is Closed!");
   }
   m_clientSocket.Send(buffer);

}
```

Questions:

I can't see anything that i'm doing substantially different with my new code to existing but the socket isn't being written to. Can anyone spot anything obvious ? Is this something to do with sockets, handles and references to them ?

EDIT: Bug found, whilst I was looking up to see if the socket existed, I was passing in the socket of the sender not receiver. I'll fix this.
Debugging DLL's I'd still like to know about though..

Secondly, the project is setup with the socket handling in it's own DLL called Communication.Sockets.Core. I've never built DLL's before and i'm having trouble debugging. Can't use normal debug points in code - I resorted to creating a form to display instead.

[image: Solution Explorer]

Any tips on how to debug DLL's ?

I'm still fairly new to C#; just on 1 year.

TIA,

Andrew

Comment: You need to be more familiar with Visual Studio in this case to see why break points fail. Besides, troubleshooting socket issues also require experience on network protocols. Therefore, learning System.Net tracing (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947285), Wireshark/Microsoft Network Monitor is mandate.